# JUnit suite doesn't run in loop

Tags: java, junit4

I have some tests (assume Test1, Test2) under one suite AllTests, see the code:

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({ Test1.class, Test2.class})
public class AllTests {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(AllTests.class);
            for (Failure failure : result.getFailures()) {
                System.out.println(failure.toString());
            }
        }
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public static void runBeforeClass() {
        System.out.println("BEFORE:");
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void runAfterClass() {
        System.out.println("AFTER:");
    }
}
```

When I put `Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(AllTests.class);` under loop the suite runs only one sequence [Test1, Test2].

### **Questions:**

1. How can I run AllTest in loop [[Test1, Test2], [Test1, Test2],.....] ?
2. When I run (1) how can I pass parameters to Test1 only in such a sequence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question:
**1.** I just removed the main function from AllTests class and created another class MasterTest that is a JUnit suite of suites.

AllTest class:

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({ Test1.class, Test2.class})
public class AllTests {  
   // This class used for suiting the test classes
}
```

And I can run AllTests in MasterTest many times:

```
  @RunWith(Suite.class)
    @SuiteClasses({ AllTests.class, AllTests.class, AllTests.class})
    public class MasterTest {  
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(AllTests.class);
                for (Failure failure : result.getFailures()) {
                    System.out.println(failure.toString());                
                }
        }
    }
```

**2.** About parameters: the parametrized test doesn't good for me because throu one run of AllTests if I give for example to Test1 3 parameters I get the following sequence: [Test1, Test1, Test1, Test2], So I created a singletone class that contains all parameters and use a static counter to return different value for each call.

Answer (score 2):

> the suite runs only one sequence [Test1, Test2].

If you look at Junit wiki
https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Aggregating-tests-in-suites

> // the class remains empty, used only as a holder for the above annotations

hence the code inside class is never executed and suite runs one sequence due to following line in your code

> @SuiteClasses({ Test1.class, Test2.class})

In suite the tests are executed independently and so u can execute Test1 and Test2 one after another using for loop.

Regarding passing parameters to Test1 only.
I think its not possible in Junit. But if you want to test methods of Test1 for various values of input parameters, may be you can use parameterized constructors.